# Developing high load sites with java

Tags: java

Is there any web sites written with java that serve millions of users?

From what I've seen, popular web sites generally using php, asp.net. Is this because of servlet technology or development costs?

===============After close===========

I am currently developing web applications  using JSF ,Spring MVC +JQUERY . In the past  ,I  had  developed web applications using  asp.net . Applications we developed are  seems to me and Workmates(they have mostly php  experince) slow .So we want to know  ,

Are we missing something   or Servlet  technology come with cons.

For this,  I ask  the question and  its  a reasonable question.

Comment: I am mostly curious about servlet  side of web site not business logic implementation  parts.

Comment: It would be a bit cumbersome to have business logic in Java not *exposed* in any way by servlet mechanism provided the application is deployed on Java based servlet container/application server

Comment: @Wojtek O  SOA architecture quite popular for that kind of sites.

Comment: @duffymo  Why closed  this question .It  is a reasonable question.I use asp.net ,jsf and Spring MVC +JQUERY  .And currently going on Spring MVC but web  applications developed servlet seem slower to me.And I want to know is this result from servlet tecnology.

Answer (score 3):

Do GMail, EBay, Twitter and Amazon count? I would characterize them as popular and high-load.

Comment: are  these sites using servlets or  their business logic implemented in java

Comment: AFAIK GMail is Javascript server- and clientside

Comment: Amazon at least does. See http://highscalability.com/amazon-architecture

Comment: Twitter seems to use a spacific Java server based on Netty: http://www.infoq.com/articles/twitter-java-use

Comment: Ebay does use servlets as well: http://highscalability.com/ebay-architecture

Answer (score 2):

http://twitter.com/ is serving quite a few requests per second.

Comment: and is quite often over capacity :-) ;-) heee heee... what an irony